# I'm a Werewolf. How do I become a Vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've already become a werewolf in Skyrim, but how do you become a vampire? Is there anything special I need to do, or things I shouldn't do?

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to ensure you become a Vampire?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41752/4797)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot become a vampire while you are a werewolf because werewolves are immune to all diseases, so you cannot contract [Sanguinare Vampiris](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sanguinare_Vampiris)

If you cure your werewolf issue, then you can contract the disease simply by allowing a vampire to do damage to you until you receive it.

Afterwards, idling for 72 hours will turn you into a full fledged vampire.

Comment: Rumor has it there is a bug that prevents a cured ex-werewolf from becoming a vampire, so please let us know if this actually works?

Comment: there is a bug that prevents this from happening if you are an ex werewolf.

Answer (score 2):

You can be a vampire while you are a werewolf only with the Dawnguard expansion. Serana or her father can turn you either way.

Comment: You can *become* a vampire lord when you are a werewolf, but you will be "cured" of your lycanthropy in the process.