# Not recognized as vampire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

My character seems to reset each time I change to a vampire lord and back again. I am still considered a vampire by everyone in the game except for Lord Harkon and his court. The only physical change that occurs is that my eyes are no longer glowing. I think the problem may be that I am changed to the version of vampirism that came before Dawnguard. How can I fix the problem or keep my character from reverting?

Forgot to add this earlier, I am running Skyrim on a PC.

Comment: I doubt the problem is being infected before Dawnguard, but if you like you can try curing yourself by becoming a werewolf or by giving a filled black soul gem to Falion in Morthal.

Comment: I tried to do that several times with no luck. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Got any mods running? Might be one of them.

Comment: When you say 'changed to' if you mean you did it through the console instead of game mechanics then its likely your game is just in a bad state now. I am not sure short of more console fiddling if you can get it to a normal state again.

Comment: @kotekzot Yes, I do have some mods and am currently trying to figure out if any of them are causing the problem.

Comment: @james By 'changed to' I simply mean used the Vampire Lord power. I probably will have to fix it using the console though.

Answer (score 3):

Background info on how I came upon my solution: (If it's TLDR, just skip directly to the solution further below.)

I experienced a similar issue and have been able to fix it. In my case, it is because the Companions turned me into a Werewolf from being a Vampire Lord. I had none of the [Vampire's abilities and weaknesses](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism#Active_Effects_and_Abilities), except Resist Disease 100% and I still have the ability to turn into a Vampire Lord. While at the same time, I also have the ability to turn into a Werewolf (Beast Form) and have the Werewolf 'Resist Disease 100%' ability (yes, I had two Resist Disease 100% abilities), making me some sort of messed-up [Vampire-Werewolf hybrid](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid). Clearly, something must have messed up when the Companions turned me into a werewolf.

Like what happened in your case, Lord Harkon and his court won't recognize me as a vampire. That is except for Serana, which recognizes me as a vampire and doesn't give me the conversation option to turn me back into a Vampire Lord. Entering the `player.setrace <player race>racevampire` [console command](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) gets me recognized as a vampire by the court (Serana still won't give me the conversation option to turn me back into a Vampire Lord), but I still had none of the Vampire abilities and weaknesses I previously mentioned.

#### Solution (or: TLDR)

- I entered the `player.setrace <player race>racevampire` [console command](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) (I'm not sure of an alternate method for the console command for non-PC players, but you could try either [turning into a Vampire, vanilla-style](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41752/4797) or just continue to Falion as I will further explain below.)
- Get [Falion](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falion) to cure me of my Vampirism, through the [Rising at Dawn](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rising_at_Dawn) quest (which also cured me of my Lycanthropy, for some weird reason).
- Go back to Serana, who now recognizes me as a non-Vampire and now gives the conversation option to turn me back into a Vampire Lord.
- After I let Serana turn me back into a Vampire Lord, I am now not a messed-up Vampire-Werewolf hybrid. I now have all the abilities and weaknesses of a Vampire and have no Werewolf abilities anymore. Damn Companions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used **console command** to set your race in game? For example if you are wood elf.

```
player.setrace woodelfracevampire
```

Hope this helps!

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_%28Skyrim%29#Using_console_commands).