# I'm a werewolf but suddenly the game gave me vampire powers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am a werewolf, and I finished the Dawnguard DLC a while ago.

But as I was going through a ruin, my game started giving me notifications as if I were a vampire. I never got notified that I contracted the disease and my eyes don't glow but now my blood boils in the sunlight and I have Vampire's Seduction and Vampire's Thrall. I can still transform into a werewolf and if I go into the game stats and look at the "days as a vampire" stat it never changes even as several days have gone by.

I've tried to trigger the Rising at Dawn quest by talking to Falion and there isn't even an opportunity. I've also used a Cure Disease potion as soon as I noticed the sunlight thing and when that didn't work, I tried using the Shrine of Talos in Whiterun...

Is there any saving this or am I just screwed? Has anyone else had this problem? Will it impact my save data?

Comment: Are you able to feed?

Answer (score 2):

Vampirism and lycanthropy are *supposed* to be mutually exclusive. You are not supposed to have both at once, and so you should not have contracted vampirism. But you did, somehow, so how do we fix it?

There are several options, depending on what you want to do next:

- The "simple" fix is to run `player.setrace <your race>racevampire` at the console (e.g. `player.setrace bretonracevampire` if you are a Breton). According to [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism#Bugs), this will cause Falion to recognize you as a vampire, and you can then proceed with curing yourself as normal (or not, if you prefer).
- If you cannot run console commands, then you should progress the Dawnguard main quest until you have the option of becoming a vampire lord, and then do so. Harkon will offer this to you early on in the quest, but there is another opportunity later on if you do not want to side with the Volkihar. This will have the side effect of removing your lycanthropy. You can regain it from Aela, once, but if you lose it a second time, it will be gone for good. Note that the Dawnguard main quest cannot be progressed if your vampirism doesn't match the faction you sided with (i.e. if you side with the Dawnguard, they will expect you to cure your vampirism, and if you side with the Volkihar, they will expect you to remain a vampire), so think carefully about whether you want to cure it before doing so.
- There are also various mods which allow both vampirism and lycanthropy to be obtained by other means. This can be used to circumvent Aela's "one time only" restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the same situation during my playthough and I believe that the reason was that I had **Ring of Namira** equipped and being feeding on corpses while having it equipped after going through "The Taste of Death" quest. Can you check if you have that ring equipped?

Answer (score 0):

[I have experienced a similar issue where I also became a Vampire-Werewolf hybrid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136743/4797) I've been able to fix it using these steps:

- I entered the `player.setrace <player race>racevampire` [console command](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console).
- I then got [Falion](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falion) to cure me of my Vampirism, through the [Rising at Dawn](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rising_at_Dawn) quest (which also cured me of my Lycanthropy, for some weird reason).

Note: You can go back to being a Werewolf by following the instructions mentioned in [this answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136861/4797)

Background info:

In my case, I became a Vampire-Werewolf hybrid because the Companions turned me into a Werewolf from being a Vampire Lord. I had none of the [Vampire's abilities and weaknesses](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism#Active_Effects_and_Abilities), except Resist Disease 100% and I still have the ability to turn into a Vampire Lord. While at the same time, I also have the ability to turn into a Werewolf (Beast Form) and have the Werewolf 'Resist Disease 100%' ability (yes, I had two Resist Disease 100% abilities), making me some sort of messed-up Vampire-Werewolf hybrid. Clearly, something must have messed up when the Companions turned me into a werewolf.

Lord Harkon and his court won't recognize me as a vampire. That is except for Serana, who recognizes me as a vampire and doesn't give me the conversation option to turn me back into a Vampire Lord. Entering the `player.setrace <player race>racevampire` [console command](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) gets me recognized as a vampire by the court (Serana still won't give me the conversation option to turn me back into a Vampire Lord), but I still had none of the Vampire abilities and weaknesses I previously mentioned.