# How can I contract vampirism ASAP?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It seems that the earliest way to contract vampirism is via [random event](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions#Random_Events) after escaping Helgen (at the beginning of the game). If so, is there a consistent way to do it?

It is important to me that the means is legitimate, but information about less-legitimate means may still prove useful and I am willing to cheat to simulate optimal RNG.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to ensure you become a Vampire?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41752/4797)

Answer (score 6):

There is a vampire cave if you head east into the mountains after leaving Helgan. Should be the road to Iverstead.
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Haemar's_Shame

Answer (score 3):

You can always just run commands in the console.

To forcibly get *Sanguine Vampiris*, simply run `player.addspell xx0037E9` in the console. Replace the `xx` with the Dawnguard DLC Load code (Usually 02, but may vary).

If you don't have Dawnguard, use `player.addspell 000B8780`.