# How do I become a vampire after I've been a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly does lycanthropy work?  Does it mix with vampirism?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34905/how-exactly-does-lycanthropy-work-does-it-mix-with-vampirism)
>   [Has anyone actually cured lycanthropy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy)
>   [How do I become a vampire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36449/how-do-i-become-a-vampire)

I've been a werewolf, and now I want to be a vampire. What do I need to do, and how do I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36449/how-do-i-become-a-vampire, and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34905/how-exactly-does-lycanthropy-work-does-it-mix-with-vampirism

Answer (score 2):

To cure lycanthrapy you must finish the Companions quest line, and finish the radiant quest "Purity". Once you have done that, you can catch Vampirism disease by battling a vampire.

Once you have the disease, you must wait 72 hours, and you will be a vampire.

However once you have cured lycanthrapy you cant catch it again (And so cant be a werewolf)